# Properties of subspaces of metric spaces

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and E ⊂ X. I have to demonstrate:

(a) $\partial E$ is closed;

(b) $ \partial (\partial E) \subset \partial E$;

(c) The inclusion in (b) can be strict

---

My work is as follows:

(a) $\forall x_0 \in \partial E, \space x_0 \notin X \backslash \partial E, \space \exists x_0 \space \forall x \in X \backslash \partial E : x \to x_0 \Rightarrow x \neq x_0 $ then $ X \backslash \partial E \space $  is open, then $ \partial E \space $ is closed;

(b) I know that $\partial E = \overline E  \cap \overline {E^c}$ and $\partial (\partial E) = (\overline E  \cap \overline {E^c}) \cap (\overline E  \cap \overline {E^c})^c$ so $(\overline E  \cap \overline E^c) \cap (\overline E  \cap \overline {E^c})^c \subset (\overline E  \cap \overline {E^c})$ but I don't think this help me. I don't realy know how to go further.

(c) To me $ \partial (\partial E)$ and $ \partial E$ are the same thing so i don't understand this point at all.

---

(c) If I take $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb R$ in exame, i think: $\overline {\Bbb Q} = \Bbb Q \cup D(\Bbb Q), \space D(\Bbb Q):=\{All \space the \space accumulation \space point \space \space of \space \Bbb Q\}$ because $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$, so  $\overline {\Bbb Q} = \Bbb R, \space \partial {\Bbb Q} = \Bbb R \cap \Bbb R^c, \Bbb R^c = \emptyset, \space then \space \partial \Bbb Q = \Bbb R \cap \emptyset \space so \space \partial \Bbb Q = \emptyset$

I'm missing something this must be incorrect, how can i go on?

---

Second take

(b) I'd like to dimonstarte the sentance: For any closed set $C, \partial C \subset C$.
Can somebody give me a hint?

(c) I take $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb R$ in exame:

 $D(\Bbb Q):= \{All \space the \space accumulation \space point \space \space of \space \Bbb Q\} = \Bbb R$ (Because $ \Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$) 

 $\overline {\Bbb Q} = \Bbb Q \cup D(\Bbb Q) = \Bbb R, \space and \space \overline {\Bbb Q^c} = \Bbb R \space so \space, \partial (\Bbb Q) = \overline {\Bbb Q} \cap \overline {\Bbb Q^c} = \Bbb R$, 

$(\partial (\Bbb Q))^c = \Bbb R^c=\emptyset \space so \space \partial (\partial (\Bbb Q)) =\partial (\Bbb R) = \Bbb R \cap \Bbb R^c = \emptyset \space then \space \partial (\partial (Q)) = \emptyset$

Is that correct? I hope so.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please learn MathJax typesetting and if a question looks like it could be homework please show any own attempts you've made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) Consider $(\partial E)^c=(\overline{E})^c\cup(E-\partial E)$. The first set is the complement of a closed set and so is open and the second is the complement of $\overline{E^c}$ and so is also open. The union of two open sets is open, so $((\partial E)^c)^c=\partial E$ is closed.

b) For any closed set $C$, $\partial C\subseteq C$. By a) $\partial E$ is closed, so we are done.

c) Note that $E=\partial E$ if and only if $E$ has empty interior. Although intuitively it might seem like every boundary has empty interior, this is not true. Think about $\mathbb{Q}$ sitting inside of $\mathbb{R}$ in the usual way. What is it's boundary? **HINT:** the answer is not $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I'd like to dimonstarte the sentance: For any closed set $C, \partial C \subset C$.
Can you give me a hint?

Comment: @DiDi This might be trivial depending on your definitions, but show that $\overline{C}$ is the smallest closed set containing $C$, and is equal to $C\cup\partial C$. My assertion follows from those two.

Comment: I thought about your hint but I'm stack. Maybe I found another way: if $C$ is any closed set, and we have $\partial (C) = \overline C \cap \overline {C^c}$ then $\partial (C) \subset \overline C$ necessarily, is that ok?

Comment: @DiDi Yeah, that works too. You also have to point out that $C=\overline{C}$.

Answer (score 0):

$\partial E$ is the intersection of two closed sets and is therefore closed.

Since $\partial E$ is closed we have $\partial (\partial E)=\overline {\partial E}\cap \overline {(\partial E)^c}\subset \overline {\partial E}=\partial E.$

When $X=\mathbb R$ and $E=\mathbb Q$ we have $\partial E=\mathbb R=X$ and $\partial(\partial E)=\partial X=\phi.$